# SQLalchemy hierarchical hybrid-transformation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, hierarchical

BASED on http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#hybrid-transformers

Hello fellow sqlalchemy coders!

I have a data of the form:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import Comparator

class GrandparentTransformer(Comparator):
    def operate(self, op, other):
        def transform(q):
            cls = self.__clause_element__()
            parent_alias = aliased(cls)
            return q.join(parent_alias, cls.parent).\
                        filter(op(parent_alias.parent, other))
        return transform

Base = declarative_base()

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id =Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    parent = relationship("Node", remote_side=id)

    @hybrid_property
    def grandparent(self):
        return self.parent.parent

    @grandparent.comparator
    def grandparent(cls):
        return GrandparentTransformer(cls)
```

It would be realy neat If I could extend Node class to support predecessor(n) "property".
So that instead of simple grandparent i could use it as:

```
node.predecessor(0) == node
node.predecessor(1) == node.parent
node.predecessor(2) == node.parent.parent == node.grandparent
(...etc...)
```

and

```
session.query(Node).with_transformation(Node.grandparent.join).filter(Node.grandparent==None)
```

would be equal to:

```
session.query(Node).with_transformation(Node.predecessor(2).join).filter(Node.predecessor(2)==None)
```

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:**
How to implement "xpath" on structure like above?

If i have a tree:

```
N0(n='A')
 -N01(n='S')
 -N02(n='S')
   -N021(n='V')
   -N022(n='N')
     -N0221(n='N')
 -N03(n='Ab')
```

path to node N03 = ['A','Ab']

path to node N0221 = ['A','S','N','N']

Goal:
**"Find all nodes whose ancestors have [X,Y,...] anywhere in their hierarchy"**
For example query for argument (['S','N']) would return nodes:

N022

N0221

because their path is as follows:

N022 - path=A,S,N

N0221- path=A,S,N,N

Above can be generalized to match not only by node.name.

It could be involed as follows: (proposal)

```
session.query(Node).xpath('//[@name=S]/[@name=N]/*')
```

or something similar

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, aliased
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import Comparator, hybrid_property, hybrid_method

class GrandparentTransformer(Comparator):
    def __init__(self, expression, levels):
        self.expression = expression
        self.levels = levels

    def operate(self, op, other):
        def transform(q):
            cls = self.__clause_element__()
            for i in xrange(self.levels):
                parent_alias = aliased(cls)
                q = q.join(parent_alias, cls.parent).\
                            filter(op(parent_alias.parent, other))
                cls = parent_alias
            return q
        return transform

Base = declarative_base()

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    parent = relationship("Node", remote_side=id)

    @hybrid_property
    def grandparent(self):
        return self.predecessor(2)

    @hybrid_method
    def predecessor(self, n):
        if n == 0:
            return self
        else:
            return self.parent.predecessor(n - 1)

    @predecessor.expression
    def predecessor(cls, n):
        return GrandparentTransformer(cls, n)

n1, n2, n3, n4 = Node(), Node(), Node(), Node()
n1.parent = n2
n2.parent = n3
n3.parent = n4

assert n1.predecessor(2) is n3 is n1.grandparent
assert n1.predecessor(1) is n2
assert n1.predecessor(0) is n1

session = Session()

print session.query(Node).with_transformation(Node.grandparent == Node(id=5))

print session.query(Node).with_transformation(Node.predecessor(2) == Node(id=5))

print session.query(Node).with_transformation(Node.predecessor(5) == Node(id=5))
```